# Call javascript function using PHP and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php

This is my situation:

I have this already loaded page (commenting page).

I can fetch new comments using a javascript function (Ajax).

I can post comments as well.

The thing is, when I post a comment, I want to fetch new comments at the same time. (So the user sees his uploaded comment.)

Sadly, my comment fetching script is way faster than my comment-upload script, which makes javascript look for new comments BEFORE my comment is done uploading.

Result: The user doesnt sees his uploaded comment.

Solution:

When I upload a comment, thanks to Ajax, my server sends me a success message when the comment is published. Alongside that message, I want to tell the client to execute a javascript function. I tried the following:

```html
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">reloadcom('2','1','1','/rte/richtexteditor');</script>";
```

But it doesnt work...

So my question is: can you call a javascript function using PHP and Ajax?

Edit: My client-side code (javascript)
My comment-fetching thingy:

```js
function reloadcom(q,n,p,wd){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  if(p>1){
   var div = document.getElementById("commentsection").innerHTML += this.responseText;
   document.getElementById("loadmore").remove();
  }else{
      document.getElementById("commentsection").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
    }
  };
   // GET parameters (page number, sort by newest/oldest, etc)
  xhttp.open("GET", wd + "/show.php?q=" + q + "&p= "+ p +"&n=" + n, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

My comment-uploading thingy (Its big because im not using  tags- those tags creates bugs on mobile devices, for obscure reasons):

```js
function submit(args,wd){
 if(args=="1"){
  var msg="Loading preview...";
  var arg="true";
  }else{
  var msg="Publishing comment...";
  var arg="false";
  }
   document.getElementById("message_interpreter").innerHTML='<div class="rtextcomment rtextinfo"><div class="load"></div>'+msg+'</div>';
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("message_interpreter").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", wd + "/interpreter.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("name="+escape(document.getElementById("rtextname").value)+"&message="+escape(document.getElementById("rtextcontent").value)+"&prev="+arg);
document.getElementById("cooldown").style="filter:brightness(50%);pointer-events:none";
setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById("cooldown").style="filter:brightness(100%)";
 }, 3000);
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Rather than fetching new comments at the same time as uploading, why not wait until you receive a success message from the upload before you do the fetch? If the fetch doesn't take very long that won't be much of an impact. So just move the line of code that does the fetch into the success function.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do, @Nick . The thing is that the success message comes from the server, my PHP script (the server is validating user input). Which means the success message can also return an error.

Comment: You should consider posting your code for more elaboration.

Comment: It would probably be easier to answer if you could share your JS code.

Comment: @Nick Updated..

Comment: Presumably you already know in your page the correct values to pass to `reloadcom`? In that case you can just add the call `reloadcom('2','1','1','/rte/richtexteditor');` after this line: `document.getElementById("message_interpreter").innerHTML=this.responseText;`